# How to print the last line of each group for long line list in command line using awk or any?

Tags: bash, awk

Using grep for many files in bash, each file shows several lines. So I want to get the one final line for each file.
After using grep, the output is like this,

```
- re0_400.out:  18 F= -.36810451E+02 E0= -.36810451E+02  d E =-.133023E-01
- re0_400.out:  19 F= -.36810451E+02 E0= -.36810451E+02  d E =-.133024E-01
- re0_400.out:  20 F= -.36797147E+02 E0= -.36797147E+02  d E =0.137473E-05
- re0_400s.out:   1 F= -.18286638E+02 E0= -.18286638E+02  d E =-.182866E+02
- re0_400s.out:   2 F= -.18277347E+02 E0= -.18277347E+02  d E =0.929017E-02
- re0_400s.out:   3 F= -.18293043E+02 E0= -.18293043E+02  d E =-.640539E-02
- re0_400s.out:   4 F= -.18293044E+02 E0= -.18293044E+02  d E =-.640678E-02
- re0_450.out:   1 F= -.36767212E+02 E0= -.36767212E+02  d E =-.367672E+02
- re0_450.out:   2 F= -.36750221E+02 E0= -.36750221E+02  d E =0.169913E-01
- re0_450.out:   3 F= -.36780151E+02 E0= -.36780151E+02  d E =-.129382E-01
- re0_450.out:   4 F= -.36780151E+02 E0= -.36780151E+02  d E =-.129384E-01
```

Code tried is:

```
awk '$1=="BB" && $2>1 {print f} {f=$1}' a.txt
```

This is a code ([Print previous line if condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27740937/print-previous-line-if-condition-is-met)) to print the previous line when a field meets a condition. But in my case, I need to compare the same fields in two lines.

The results should be

```
- re0_400.out:  20 F= -.36797147E+02 E0= -.36797147E+02  d E =0.137473E-05
- re0_400s.out:   4 F= -.18293044E+02 E0= -.18293044E+02  d E =-.640678E-02
- re0_450.out:   4 F= -.36780151E+02 E0= -.36780151E+02  d E =-.129384E-01
```

How to get this result in bash using awk or any command in shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following (here I have considered that your Input_file has `-`  hashes shown by you in samples,in case you don't have them then try changing `$2` to `$1`in following code).

```
awk '
!a[$2]++{
  b[++count]=$2
}
{
  c[$2]=$0
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print c[b[i]]
  }
}
'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
- re0_400.out:  20 F= -.36797147E+02 E0= -.36797147E+02  d E =0.137473E-05
- re0_400s.out:   4 F= -.18293044E+02 E0= -.18293044E+02  d E =-.640678E-02
- re0_450.out:   4 F= -.36780151E+02 E0= -.36780151E+02  d E =-.129384E-01
```

---

---

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                         ##Starting awk program from here.
!a[$2]++{                     ##Checking condition if $2 is NOT present in array a then put $2 in array a, so this condition will make sure each filename is coming only once in arrays.
  b[++count]=$2               ##Creating an array named b whose index is variable count with increment number 1 each time and its value is $2 of current line.
}                             ##Closing BLOCK for  this condition here.
{
  c[$2]=$0                    ##Creating an array named c whose index is $2 and value is $0. Since OP needs ALWAYS the LATEST line for files so this will keep over-writing the lines values of same file names and maintain latest file name value only.
}
END{                          ##Starting END section of this awk program here.
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){      ##Starting a for loop from i=1 to till value of count, where variable count actually having number of file names($1 or $2, $1 without hashes in your Input_file and with hashes $2).
    print c[b[i]]             ##We are printing array c whose index is b[i] which will be having exact line value.
  }                           ##Closing for loop BLOCK here.
}
'  Input_file                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```